# Determine if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac2n)^n$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have an infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{2}{n})^n$.  I need to show if it converges or diverges using any test.  I've tried applying all of the tests that I know, and hit dead ends with each.  I must have made a mistake somewhere but I can't figure it out.  Here's the tests/steps I used but I'm not sure if I applied the rules correctly:

Divergence test: The test is inconclusive because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2+n}{n}\right)^n$ produces $1^\infty$ which is an indeterminate form.

**Edit:  The limit actually doesn't produce an indeterminate form, as pointed out in comments...so the divergence test shows that it diverges.**

Geometric Series:  I couldn't figure out how to apply this test because what would be "$r$" has $n$ in the denominator.

Integral test:  I tried writing the integral $\int_1^\infty{\left(\frac{2+n}{n}\right)^n}dn$, but I'm not sure how to solve this because when I simplified the function inside by distributing the power to the numerator and denominator, I got $n^n$ which I'm not sure how to integrate.

Root test:  When I applied this test, I got 1, which means the test is inconclusive.

Ratio test:  When I applied this test, I wasn't sure how to go further after a few steps of simplification.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2+(n+1)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2+n}\right)^n$$

Some simplifying:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3+n)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n^2}{(2+n)^n}$$

Here, I'm not sure how to simplify it further because the bases are different so I can't simply add the exponents, and I can't see that it simplifies any further.  Plugging in infinity to the n's produces multiple indeterminate forms of $\infty^\infty$.

Perhaps I'm missing something simple, or I made a mistake applying the tests somewhere, but I'm stuck and not sure what I missed.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the $n$-th term go to zero? There is this number, $e$.

Comment: By the binomial theorem, $$\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n = \frac{(n+2)^n}{n^n}\geq\frac{n^n+2n\cdot n^{n-1}}{n^n}=3.$$

Comment: Remember this:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n = e^x $$

Comment: The ratio test can work too, if you take the log of the limit, but the above is easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the limit of the sequence

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n$$

You should find that this is nonzero, so that your series diverges.

Comment: That was the first test I applied but taking the limit produces $1^\infty$, an indeterminate form.  So even though it's indeterminate, it still counts as "non zero"?

Comment: Well, it's not indeterminate, you can certainly find its limit to be $e^2$ (or at the very least to be greater than or equal to $1$)

Comment: Notice that $1+\frac{2}{n}>1$. When you raise *any* number greater than $1$ to a positive power, it is necessarily greater than $1$...

Comment: I see, I didn't think to transform the limit by writing $e^{(\lim)}$, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sabien: Do you know how to deal with indeterminate forms?  We can use L'Hopital as is done in Chris's post, or we can use the fact that $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams (pedantry: given that there's a limiting process involved, it's probably worth noting that this means that the limits are _at least_ one - but the important part, of course, is that it's bounded away from zero regardless.)

Answer (score 2):

Should be obvious that your series is bigger then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1+e_n$$
for some $e_i> 0$ for all $i$, which is clearly divergent.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to evaluate

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+2/n)^n \\
= \exp(\lim n\cdot \log(1+2/n)) \\
= \exp(\lim \frac{-2/n^2}{-(1+2/n)/n^2}) \\
= \exp(2) \neq 0.$$

Note that a necessary condition for convergence would be that this limit goes to $0$.

But a less computationally-intensive method would be using the comparison test: compare each term with $1$.